# Background Image doesn't cover entire webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As the title says, my background image doesn't cover the entire page. I've been messing around with various settings with no luck.

Here are the links to CSS and HTML content:

https://cs.iupui.edu/~jweilham/n341/background.html

https://cs.iupui.edu/~jweilham/n341/background.css

Comment: You want to use vh units for the height. I do like the dropdown menus you made by the way ;).

Comment: I m assuming the height is the issue by the way, since your page displays okay in Google chrome.

Comment: By the way if you want the background to remain in place even when scrolling use `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 2):

Add your background inside body tag

```
html, body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    margin: 50px;
    background: url("clouds.png");
}
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: It makes the image cover the whole page but it also causes the image to no longer scroll side to side.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctyle, the issue is that when you scroll down, the image does not cover the rest of the page. You can fix this very easily. On your css file, just replace `position: absolute` with `position: fixed`.

```
#animatedBackground {
   position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: It makes the image cover the whole page but it also causes the image to no longer scroll side to side.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is div#animatedBackground is not containing the rest of the html

Put all html tags inside the `div id ='animatedBackground'`

```
<div id="animatedBackground">
     // All other including div#accordion,fieldset,form
</div>
```